# loops without unrolling in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand the concept of tensorflow's computational graph. More specifically, how to implement a loop. Imagine I wish to multiply a constant by 2 for 4 times:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def tf_mul(op):
  return tf.mul(op,2.)

s=tf.placeholder_with_default(10.0,[])
```

The usual way to do it would be to unroll the graph four times and create an operation and evaluate it for at the end.

```
for i in range(4):
  s = tf_mul(s)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print sess.run(s)
```

which returns the correct answer of 160. but if I check the operations, I see that `Mul` operation was created four times, which is a waste of operations.
To avoid the creation of these "redundant" operations, the only way that comes to my mind is to replace the previous block with the following:

```
my_op=tf_mul(s)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  answer=my_op.eval(session=sess)
  for i in range(3):
    answer=my_op.eval(session=sess,feed_dict={s:answer})
  print answer
```

this also gives the correct answer and creates the `Mul` operation only once, however, it is highly inefficient because I have to evaluate `my_op` four times even though I only care for the final answer. This has happened because I cannot feed in a tensor to the feed_dict.

Now my question is if there is a more efficient way to implement this recurrent loop without extra evaluations? should I care about creating these extra operations?

Comment: you can use `tf.while_loop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TensorFlow provides various [constructs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/) for control flow, including conditionals and looping. In your case, [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#while_loop) is the most relevant construct to use. Here is a complete working example :

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
i = tf.constant(0)
x = tf.constant(10.0)
i, x = tf.while_loop(lambda i, _: i < 4, lambda i, x: (i + 1, x * 2.0), [i, x])
sess.run([i, x])
[4, 160.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is a simpler example than what you actually intend so I'll answer for both this example and for the more general case.

for this case one can do:

```
s=tf.placeholder_with_default(10.0,[])
exponent=tf.placeholder_with_default(4,[])
def tf_mul(op, exponent):
    return tf.pow(op * 2, exponent)
```

In general to not have to use for loops one should work with vector operations.

Simple example adding elements in a list:

```
sum = 0
for i in list:
    sum += i
```

Vectorized:

```
ones = tf.ones(shape=tf.get_shape(list))
sum = ones * list # the dot product
```

Comment: Yes, as you've imagined, that problem was just a [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example). The function tf_mul could be a formidable graph in its own account.